# PHP Unit and SeleniumTest_ simplified cofiguration

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, functional-testing

I am newbie in PHPunit with SeleniumTest.

http://phpunit.de/manual is not clear for me. there is so many options and I tryed many of them but dont know how to connect to work all together.

I have One test suite, in test suite there are 4 test cases.

I would like to know next thing:

- do I need to have in each test case script SetUp() and tearDown() ??
- how to connect with my SQL database ??

this is one of 4 test cases:

```
<?php
class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("*firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://blabla.com");
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("/");
    $this->type("id=signin_username", "john");
    $this->type("id=signin[password]", "1234567");
    $this->click("id=tsubmit");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    $this->open("/shoes");
    $this->assertEquals("RE", $this->getText("//div[@id='sf_admin_content']/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]"));
    $this->open("/shoes/7");
    $this->assertEquals("Status: Active", $this->getText("//div[@id='sf_fieldset_account']/div[2]"));
    $this->open("/logout");
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium test requires URL of site and browser. So you need to write setUp() in test case.
But you can write special class extending PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase, put into it setUp() and extend other your test cases.

```
<?php
class BlablaTestCase extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("*firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://blabla.com");
  }
}
```

In other file:

```
<?php
require_once 'BlablaTestCase.php';

class ExampleTestCase extends BlablaTestCase
{
  public function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("/");
    $this->type("id=signin_username", "john");
  }
}
```

But it is not necessary to devide tests for one site. You can write different tests in one test case:

```
<?php
class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("*firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://blabla.com");
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("/");
    $this->type("id=signin_username", "john");
    /* ... */
  }

  public function testMyTestCase2(){
    $this->open("/");
    $this->type("id=signin_username", "peter");
    /* ... */
  }

}
?>
```

`tearDown()` is optional. You can use it if you need to collect some results or clean up something after tests.

**You should not connect to your SQL DB in Selenium test**. All Selenium tests run in browser, do UI interactions like user.

Comment: I need to access DB, it is mandatory, because it is not possible to perform tests without some basic information.